# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre display: block, display: inline y display: inline-block?

Tags: html, html5, css

He encontrado varias dudas acerca de la diferencia a la hora de trabajar con estos tipos de elementos en CSS.

Entonces, ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre estos elementos?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Resumen

- **inline:** Muestra en la misma línea (respetando el flujo) todos los elementos y no acepta las propiedades width, height ni margenes verticales.
- **block:** Muestra los elementos en líneas independientes y acepta las propiedades width, height y margenes verticales.
- **inline-block:** Su comportamiento es una mezcla entre los dos anteriores, se muestran en la misma línea (respetando el flujo) todos los elementos y además, acepta las propiedades width, height y margenes verticales.

---

Para explicarlo de manera sencilla, ciertas etiquetas HTML no se ven afectadas por el flujo de otros elementos, limitándose solamente a su uso natural.

## Elementos en línea o inline

> Los elementos en línea definidos por HTML son los siguientes: a, abbr,
>   acronym, b, basefont, bdo, big, br, cite, code, dfn, em, font, i, img,
>   input, kbd, label, q, s, samp, select, small, span, strike, strong,
>   sub, sup, textarea, tt, u, var.

Un ejemplo de estas etiquetas podría ser `<a>`, `<em>` y quizás la más útil de todas `<span>`, a todos estos elementos se les llama "inline", porque por defecto llevan su `display: inline`, sin necesidad de especificarlo en un documento CSS.

Imaginemos que tenemos el siguiente panorama:

```css
.box {
 background-color: tomato;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 50px 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Aliquam tortor turpis, convallis eget suscipit vel, eleifend
  tincidunt orci. Quisque ac.</p>
<span class="box">CAJA 1</span>
<a class="box" href="#">CAJA 2</a>
<span class="box">CAJA 3</span>
<em class="box">CAJA 4</em>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Aliquam tortor turpis, convallis eget suscipit vel, eleifend
  tincidunt orci. Quisque ac.</p>
```

Cómo vemos, todas las Cajas X tienen la propiedad inline (a pesar de no estar definido en el CSS) y se alinean unas a otras pero no se respetan anchos, ni altos y mucho menos margenes verticales

---

## Elementos en bloque o block

Por el contrario, existen los elementos en bloque, los cuales no se mezclan con el resto de los elementos, mostrándose en "líneas" independientes.

> Los elementos de bloque definidos por HTML son: address, blockquote,
>   center, dir, div, dl, fieldset, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr,
>   isindex, menu, noframes, noscript, ol, p, pre, table, ul, dd, dt, frameset, li, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr.

Volviendo al mismo panorama pero cambiando los elementos inline por elementos  de bloque, tendremos el siguiente resultado:

```css
.box {
 background-color: tomato;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 50px 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Aliquam tortor turpis, convallis eget suscipit vel, eleifend
  tincidunt orci. Quisque ac.</p>
<div class="box">CAJA 1</div>
<h6 class="box">CAJA 2</h6>
<div class="box">CAJA 3</div>
<pre class="box">CAJA 4</pre>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Aliquam tortor turpis, convallis eget suscipit vel, eleifend
  tincidunt orci. Quisque ac.</p>
```

Como lo comente, ahora los elementos bloque se muestran en "líneas" independientes pero sobre todo, ya respetan anchos, altos y margenes verticales.

---

## Elemento bloque en línea o inline-block

Acabamos de ver los elementos block y los elementos inline, ahora pues, toca continuar con el elemento inline-block.

Este elemento es una mezcla de ambos, pudiéndose alinear pero además respeta altos, anchos y margenes verticales.

```css
.box {
    display: inline-block;
 background-color: tomato;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 50px 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Aliquam tortor turpis, convallis eget suscipit vel, eleifend
  tincidunt orci. Quisque ac.</p>
<span class="box">CAJA 1</span>
<a class="box" href="#">CAJA 2</a>
<span class="box">CAJA 3</span>
<em class="box">CAJA 4</em>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Aliquam tortor turpis, convallis eget suscipit vel, eleifend
  tincidunt orci. Quisque ac.</p>
```