# Centrando elementos con CSS en Bootstrap

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap, css3

Estoy intentando centrar lo siguiente sin que pierda el responsive y no hay manera:

```
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-md-1 text-right">Periodo:</span>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input value="01/11/2016" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input value="29/11/2016" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-md-1 text-right">Select1</span>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option selected="selected" value="15">A</option>
                <option value="19">B</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-md-1 text-right">Select2</span>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select tabindex="5" class="form-control">
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="7">7</option>
                <option value="42">42</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input value="Button1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
        <input value="Button2" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
    </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNeqyY

Los botones con un `text-center` están centrados, pero los `spans` y los `textboxs` de arriba no hay manera.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el resto de elementos también queden centrados?

Comment: Hola Andrés, bienvenido. Por qué no pegas el código aquí y asi la gente se ahorra el visitar ese enlace? (que si se cae, tu pregunta queda inservible)

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima, gracias :)

Comment: Para la proxima no, puedes hacerlo ahora y mejorar tu pregunta [editandola](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/36602/edit). Aunque ya tengas una respuesta (recuerda aceptarla) es recomendable mejorar la pregunta todo lo posible. en el futuro alguien puede tener la misma duda que tú

Comment: Hecho, gracias por los consejos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes utilizar flexbox y la propiedad `justify-content: center` para tu clase `.row`.

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

De esta manera cada uno de los elementos estará centrado horizontalmente dentro de sus correspondientes líneas.

**Explicación de porque unos elementos se centran y otros no con `text-center`**

En tu caso, los botones (que en este caso son `inputs` en realidad) se están centrando con la propiedad `text-center` porque son elementos `inline` y esta propiedad solo funciona para los elementos `inline` o `inline-block`. Por lo tanto, como los `div` por defecto son elementos que actúan como bloque (`block`), no se van a centrar con esta propiedad.

**[Codepen actualizado](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/worXKd)**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapidez! Un saludo

Comment: @Andrés73 De nada! No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha resuelto tu duda. Gracias! ^^

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar el voto negativo?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer la siguiente pregunta / respuesta que yo mismo he hecho, @Andrés73 http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24964/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-display-block-display-inline-y-display-inline-b/24965#24965 Te ayudará mucho a entender tu problema.