# Por que no se aplican los estilos al nav?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una practica de css y quisiera saber por que no se estan aplicando los estilos que aplico al nav, aparentemente esta todo bien, no se que pueda ser el problema. Muchas gracias.
Este es mi html

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*:after,*:before {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
 font-family: verdana, geneva, serif;
}

header {
 padding: 20px 0;
}

div.contenedor {
 width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/** Navegación**/

nav {
 margin: 0 auto;
 backg round-color: #db008d;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Blog de Viajes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<header>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo Blog de viajes">
    </div>
  </div><!--contenedor-->
</header>

<div class="Navegación">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Misión</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Visión</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Valores</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Consejos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ciudades</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacto </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div><!--Navegación-->

<div class="contenido contenedor">
    <main>
      <article>
        <h2>Viajar a Londres</h2>
        <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="Imagen de Viajar a Londres">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <a href="#" class="Botón">Leer más</a>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Puente de la torre</h2>
        <img src="img/imagen_2.jpg" alt="Imagen del Puente de la torre">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <a href="#" class="Botón">Leer más</a>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Metro de Londres</h2>
        <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="Imagen del Metro de Londres">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <a href="#" class="Botón">Leer más</a>
      </article>
    </main>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      <h2>Otros Post</h2>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 1</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 3</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 4</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 5</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
</div><!--contenido-->

<footer>
    <div class="contendor">
      <div class="nosotros">
        <h2>Sobre Nosotros</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div><!--.nosotros-->

      <div class="menu">
        <nav>
          <h2>Menu de Navegacion</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto </a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div><!--.menu-->
   </div><!--contenedor-->

  <p class="copyright">Todos los derechos reservador &copy;. Blog de viajes 2018</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Veo que la palabra background-color  tiene un espacio

Comment: Aparte del comentario de @HectorLara, te recomendaría cambiar el nombre de la clase del nav, no usar tildes por ejemplo.

Comment: Oh, lo siento por lo del background-color, se me debio pasar al copiarlo, pero igual siguen sin aplicarse los estilos @HectorLara

Comment: Prueba a remover el display: inline; podras ver los cambios

Comment: El display inline del nav hace que se oculte, por lo que si los demás estilos te funcionan esa puede ser la razón

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los cambios si se aplicaban, simplemente no los veías por que al `<nav>` le estabas agregando la propiedad `display: inline`, al hacer esto el elemento no tendrá en cuenta ningún alto o ancho, la solución es cambiar la regla a `display: inline-block`.

**Como recomendación:** no agregues tildes a los valores de `id` o `class` de tus elementos.

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*:after,*:before {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
 font-family: verdana, geneva, serif;
}

header {
 padding: 20px 0;
}

div.contenedor {
 width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/** Navegación**/

nav {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #db008d;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo Blog de viajes">
    </div>
  </div><!--contenedor-->
</header>

<div class="Navegacion">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Misión</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Visión</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Valores</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Consejos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ciudades</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacto </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div><!--Navegación-->

<div class="contenido contenedor">
    <main>
      <article>
        <h2>Viajar a Londres</h2>
        <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="Imagen de Viajar a Londres">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <a href="#" class="Botón">Leer más</a>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Puente de la torre</h2>
        <img src="img/imagen_2.jpg" alt="Imagen del Puente de la torre">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <a href="#" class="Botón">Leer más</a>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Metro de Londres</h2>
        <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="Imagen del Metro de Londres">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <a href="#" class="Botón">Leer más</a>
      </article>
    </main>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      <h2>Otros Post</h2>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 1</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 3</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 4</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Entrada 5</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
</div><!--contenido-->

<footer>
    <div class="contendor">
      <div class="nosotros">
        <h2>Sobre Nosotros</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div><!--.nosotros-->

      <div class="menu">
        <nav>
          <h2>Menu de Navegacion</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto </a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div><!--.menu-->
   </div><!--contenedor-->

  <p class="copyright">Todos los derechos reservador &copy;. Blog de viajes 2018</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta! saludos.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!

Comment: @EduardoCanale Puedes ver más información sobre la propiedad display y sus atributos en este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24964/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-display-block-display-inline-y-display-inline-b