# Alinear 2 párrafos de manera vertical

Tags: html, css

tengo una duda básica. Tengo 2 div, y dentro de cada uno hay un párrafo.
En el css tengo los div con medida y con inline-block. Mi duda es: ¿ Porque el primer párrafo queda mas abajo que el otro? Si cambio los párrafos pasa exactamente lo mismo. El segundo párrafo queda mas abajo del primero.

```css
div{

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicingsint totam tempora ipsa. Ipsa unde nobis laborsaepe esse
            doloribus aliquam id libero.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil commodi sint ab ipsa quas quae! Temporibuslit.
            Nihil commodi sint ab ipsa quas quae! Temporibus athtrhliquid hic assumenda deserunlit. Nihil commodi sint
            atationem delectus necessitatibus natus aliquam at?</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes valerte de [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) para lograr el *alineado vertical* del o de los elementos y poder en este caso moverlos al top de su contenedor de esta forma:

```
  div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

Comment: gracias por la solucion. ¿ Sabes porque ocurre ese corrido? Tiene que ver con el div o algo asi?

Comment: @Ralexhx te comparto esta respuesta que no es mia pero igual te puede guiar sobre el tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24964/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-display-block-display-inline-y-display-inline-b